# Difference between else if and if (Java)

Tags: java, if-statement, greenfoot

I was wondering if there's any difference between these two codes:

Code 1:

```
if(isSleepy()){
    sleep(1);
} else if (isBored()){
    dance();
    dance();
} else {
    walkRight(50);
    walkLeft(50);
    if(isHungry()){
        eat();
    }
}
```

Code 2:

```
if(isSleepy()){
    sleep(1);
}
if (isBored()){
    dance();
    dance();
}
walkRight(50);
walkLeft(50);
if(isHungry()){
    eat();
}
```

I've replaced the if-elseif-if chain with if only. Does that affect the conditionnal process ?

Comment: Have you tried to run it and see what happens?

Comment: Yes. Since the boolean tired is false it would do `dance()` twice anyway in the fist case. After having danced twice, `eat()` was not called, so that's why I came here to understand the conditional process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does that affect the conditionnal process ?

Yes, it does. In the first case, `isBored()` is never called nor its result checked if `isSleepy()` returns true. In the second case, it *is* checked, it's completely independent. Similarly, `walkRight` and `walkLeft` won't be called in the first block if `isSleepy()` returns true, but they *will* be in the second block.

This reformatting of the first code block may help make things more clear;

```
if(isSleepy()){
    sleep(1);
} else {
    // The below only happens if isSleepy() returned false
    if (isBored()){
        dance();
        dance();
    } else {
        // These only happen if isSleepy() returned false AND isBored() returned false
        walkRight(50);
        walkLeft(50);
        if(isHungry()){
            eat();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. In-code comments help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`else if` is checked only in case when preceding `if` condition fails. Simple if one after the other will be executed and evaluated no matter what happened to `preceeding` if statement.

To understand simply translate `if-else` meaning

Answer (score 0):

In first case, `else` block is never checked if `else if` condition is `true` which itself is never checked if `if` condition is true.

In second case, both `if` conditions are checked and the third block isn't inside any condition, it is always executed.

> Does that affect the conditionnal process ?

In first code, the conditions are mutually exclusive but in second code both conditions may be true at the same time.